# What variable can be used in the "%{variable}" syntax in plotly

Tags: javascript, python, dataframe, plotly

The question is regarding the `'%{variable}'` syntax in the quoted code below, specifically in `hovertemplate, text` and `customdata` kwargs in the the `go.Bar()` function

```
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name=coln, x=df.index, y=df[coln], 
            # coln means columnName
            
            hovertemplate = '%{x}' + '%{y}' # <============= this thing here
            + '%{text}' + '%{customdata} + %{coln}', 
            # can access x,y,text,customdata. ie. all kwargs of this trace ("trace" is a plotly technical term, meaning, this bar plot)
            # can NOT access any other my own variables like df or coln

            customdata = [coln]*len(df.index),
            text = [
                '<b>colname==</b>:'+ another_df.loc[coln] + somefunction(coln)
                # can only do things around df and coln, not x nor y   <============= and this thing here
            ]*len(df.index),

        ) for coln in df.columns
    ],  
)
```

**Limitations I can not circumvent:**

- in `hovertemplate` kwarg, I can only access `x, y, text and customdata`, `%{coln}` won't work
- in `text` and `customdata` kwarg, I can access `coln` and `df`, but, `%{x}`
  won't work, `x` as a variable won't work. Also, `text` and
  `customdata` is the only place I can access `coln`, there are no
  other "custom data holders"
- also, since we are here, it is very cumbersome to construct `text`
  and `customdata` as a list with the same length as the plot's x axis,
  i.e. the `*len(df.index)`

**What I am looking for:**
a python f-string `f"{x} {y} {coln}"` like syntax that gives free access to `x, y, coln`, as well as free usage of `x y`, like: `df.at[x, y]` or `myfoo(x, y)` within the trace.

**P.S.**
Although the question is asking for something specific, the main objective is to go for a more flexible way of constructing hover text. Due to me being new to **plotly** and **javascript**, I may be missing lots of big pictures, so I may be approaching the situation the wrong way, please do point that out too if that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule, `texttemplate` and `hovertemplate` can access any attribute at the trace level i.e. attributes of `go.Bar()` in this case. So `x`, `y`, and `customdata` are accessible:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

go.Figure(go.Bar(
    x=["a","b"], y=[1,2], customdata=[["hi", "there"], ["hello", "there"]],
    hovertemplate="x is %{x}, y is %{y}, custom1 is %{customdata[1]}",
    texttemplate="x is %{x}, y is %{y}, custom1 is %{customdata[1]}",
    textposition="auto"
))
```

`customdata` here can be either a list of lists (as above) or a list of dicts, accessed like this:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

go.Figure(go.Bar(
    x=["a","b"], y=[1,2], customdata=[dict(hi="there"), dict(hi="here")],
    hovertemplate="x is %{x}, y is %{y}, custom1 is %{customdata.hi}",
    texttemplate="x is %{x}, y is %{y}, custom1 is %{customdata.hi}",
    textposition="auto"
))
```

The `customdata` format is compatible with Pandas' `to_dict('records')` format:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    x=["a","b"], y=[1,2], hi=["there", "here"]
))

go.Figure(go.Bar(
    x=df.x, y=df.y, customdata=df[["hi"]].to_dict('records'),
    hovertemplate="x is %{x}, y is %{y}, custom1 is %{customdata.hi}",
    texttemplate="x is %{x}, y is %{y}, custom1 is %{customdata.hi}",
    textposition="auto"
))
```

Comment: pardon the frivolous comment here, but am I being graced by the head developer of Plotly!? yeeeeeee! Nice stuff you guys are doing by the way =)

Comment: Glad you like it! I'm one of the devs here at Plotly, and I lead the data vis libraries team, yes :) Sorry our docs are not so easy to follow that you weren't able to self-serve this answer... I'll try to find a good place to explain this stuff better.

Comment: Hi there. It has been a day I am fighting to understand how to customize hovertemplate. in my data, I have a column 'level' which I want to access in the hovertemplate. I wasn't able to make it work, despite a lot or trial and error based on this post, official doc and other posts. How to make it work? and where can I find a kind of extensive of documentation for hovertemplate?

Comment: I found this one since then: https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-label-appearance - However, it's missing information relative to Sunburst charts which is the thing currently giving me headaches